# SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object hasn't property

Tags: soap-client

I make a soap server y PHP and i can access to the WSDL perfectly, but when i tested with soapclient raise me this error:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object hasn't 'ID' property in
```

Here the definition of the client:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://testwebservices.binbit.com/smart_ph/process_mo.php?wsdl',array('trace' => 1));
```

Define a `stdClass` element:

```
$data = new stdClass();
$data->userID->ID = '6235412410'; 
$data->userID->type = 0;
$data->spID = '13225124';
$data->productID = '212233223'; 
$data->serviceID = '145612354';
$data->serviceList = '552143256';
$data->updateType = 1;
$data->updateTime = '20140812346509';
$data->effectiveTime = '20140812346509';
$data->expiryTime = '5678942';
$data->notifyAttr[] = array('shortCode' => '42356');
```

And here make the action:

```
$action = $client->syncOrderRelation($data);
```

In the Xml exist an ID element:

```
<xsd:complexType name="UserID">
<xsd:all>
  <xsd:element name="ID" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="type" type="xsd:int"/>
</xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I don't undestand why happen this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution.

I have to do the UserID separately:

```
$data = new stdClass();
$data->userID->ID = '6235412410'; 
$data->userID->type = 0;
```

And the rest individualy variables:

```
$spID = '13225124';
$productID = '212233223'; 
$serviceID = '145612354';
$serviceList = '552143256';
...

$action = $client->syncOrderRelation($data,$spID,$productID,...);
```